# Multiple selection from different tables in one query

Tags: spring, mybatis

My question is about optimizing queries with mybatis.

```
List<SomeObject> someObjectList = oracleMapper.getAllSomeObject();
```

in my project I have to unload data from one database and make a request to another

```
List<String> subscriptionIds = someObjectList.stream().map(g -> g.getSubscriptionId()).collect(Collectors.toList());

     List<Subscription> subscriptionsByIds = postgresMapper.getSubscriptionsByIds(subscriptionIds);
     List<SubscriptionSubject> subjectsByIds = postgresMapper.getSubscriptionSubjectsByIds(subscriptionIds);
```

I have to do a query using a list of id to different tables twice

```
  <select id="getSubscriptionsByIds" resultType="com.mappers.Subscription">
        SELECT "s_id" as sId, "old" as old FROM "subscriptions"."subscriptions" s where s."subscription_id_old"  IN
    <foreach item="item" collection="subscriptionIds" separator="," open="(" close=")">
      #{item}
    </foreach>
  </select>

  <select id="getSubscriptionSubjectsByIds" resultType="com.mappers.SubscriptionSubject">
        SELECT  "s_id" as sId, "old" as old FROM "subscriptions"."subscription_subjects" s where s."subscription_id_old"  IN
    <foreach item="item" collection="subscriptionIds" separator="," open="(" close=")">
      #{item}
    </foreach>
  </select>

@Data
public class Subscription {
    private Long subscriptionId;
    private String subscriptionIdOld;
//others
    }


@Data
public class SubscriptionSubject {
    private Long subscriptionId;
    private String subscriptionIdOld;
//others
}
```

is it possible somehow not to do two queries, but get by with one for two tables?
There is a lot of data and there will be a lot of requests too, I would like to reduce it. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only difference between both queries is the table name. You can pass that value as an extra parameter and add it to the query using "SQL Injection".

For example:

```
<select id="getSubscriptionsByIds" resultType="com.mappers.Subscription">
  SELECT "s_id" as sId, "old" as old FROM ${tableName} s 
  WHERE s."subscription_id_old" IN
  <foreach item="item" collection="subscriptionIds" separator=","
    open="(" close=")">
    #{item}
  </foreach>
</select>
```

Make sure the object you are passing as a parameter includes an extra property `tableName` apart from the list of IDs you are already passing.

Notice that in order to implement SQL Injection you need to use `${parameter}` instead of `#{parameter}`. Use SQL Injection when absolutely necessary only. In the wrong hands it can open security vulnerabilities in your application.